# Open default Photos app with specific album / folder

Tags: android, android-intent, android-gallery, android-external-storage, android-fileprovider

Unfortunately, all existing answers to this topic are totally outdated.

I wish to launch an Intent that will open an external app with a specific images folder.
Since Android 7.0, the following method does not work:

```
Intent i=new Intent();
i.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
i.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File(path)), "image/*");  
startActivity(i);
```

I am trying using a FileProvider.
MyFileProvider:

```
public class MyFileProvider extends FileProvider {
}
```

from AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<provider
            android:name=".util.MyFileProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.common.fileprovider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/my_file_paths"/>
        </provider>
```

my_file_paths.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths>
    <files-path
        name="files"
        path="/My_bugreport"/>
    <external-path name="external_files" path="."/>
</paths>
```

Intent launch code in main activity onCreate():

```
Intent i = new Intent();
        i.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
        String path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES).getPath() + "/Pirin 1/"; // Some hard-coded folder I have on my device

        Log.d(TAG, "MyDashboardActivity: onCreate: path=" + path);

        Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, getPackageName() + ".common.fileprovider", new File(path));
        grantUriPermission(getPackageName(), uri, Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
        i.setDataAndType(uri, "image/*");
        startActivity(i);
```

I am getting the Photos app with an empty black screen and a spinning loader.
LogCat doesn't contain any useful info.
Device: Google Pixel 3

Tried many things already, many different paths, etc., almost giving up...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I wish to launch an Intent that will open an external app with a specific images folder.

There is no official support for this in Android.

> Unfortunately, all existing answers to this topic are totally outdated.

Any answer other than "there is no reliable way to do this" is wrong.

> Since Android 7.0, the following method does not work

It does not work prior to Android 7.0 either. If `path` points to a directory, then you are lying to the third-party app, saying that there is an image at that location, when there is no image there (since it is a directory, not a file). I would expect most `ACTION_VIEW` apps to not handle that well. Expecting them to magically show the contents of the directory is just wishful thinking — there is no requirement for an app that supports `ACTION_VIEW` for an image to have any ability to show the contents of a directory, let alone fall back to that behavior upon receiving a corrupt `ACTION_VIEW` `Intent`.

> I am trying using a FileProvider

`FileProvider` does not serve directories in a way that would fit your needs. For example, there is no means with `FileProvider` to get the list of content at a particular directory.

Moreover, since `ACTION_VIEW` does not support directories, you would be back where you started.

(also note that your `grantUriPermission()` call isn't going to do anything meaningful)

Comment: Thanks. Any useful / supported approach for this matter other than the things I tried?

Comment: @SirKnigget: As I wrote, there is no official support for this in Android. I cannot rule out that there is some convention for this that a few gallery-type apps support. But that will simply mean that your planned integration fails when the user chooses a different app, perhaps because their pre-installed gallery app does not support this convention. So, either use `ACTION_VIEW` to show a specific image, or implement a gallery UI in your own app, or set aside this planned feature.

Comment: Actually an interesting suggestion - since opening a single picture should be possible, maybe opening one of the pictures inside the folder will trigger a swipe-able Gallery UI (at least on some devices, on some Photos/Gallery app implementations).